# Lie bracket of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I know that for $\mathfrak{so}(3)=\mathcal{L}(SO(3))$, the set of $3\times 3$ real antisymmetric matrices, we can define a basis
$$T^1=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&0&-1\\ 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\quad
T^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\ 0&0&0\\ -1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\quad
T^3=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
such that
$$\left(T^a\right)_{bc}=-\epsilon_{abc}$$
and the Lie bracket is then
$$\left[T^a,T^b\right]=\epsilon_{abc}T^c$$
I can see that it works by explicitly putting in the matrices $T^a$ defined above, but how would one manipulate the $\epsilon$ symbols to show it formally?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, but what I meant was, using only the formal definition of $T^a$ in terms of $\epsilon_{abc}$, how do I compute the commutator $[T^a,T^b]$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Again, yes, that's the first step in expanding the commutator. The $T^a$ are then given by $(T^a)_{bc}=-\epsilon_{abc}$, i.e. $a$ is the index of the generator and $b,c$ are matrix indices (row, column). So the commutator can be expressed as some $\epsilon\epsilon-\epsilon\epsilon$. My question is then, what is the proper way of writing down the indices, and how do I simplify this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this are you looking for?
(using Einstein convention)
$$\left[T^a,T^b\right]^i_j=(T^aT^b )_{ij}-(T^bT^a )_{ij}$$
$$=(T^a)^i_p(T^b)^p_j-(T^b)^i_q(T^a)^q_j=\epsilon_{aip}\epsilon_{bpj}-\epsilon_{biq}\epsilon_{aqj}.$$
And then whatever you need to do you probably will need to use the following identity:
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{mnk}=\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}$$

**EDIT:**
Applying the formula to the previous one (if I'm not mistaking) you get
$$\left[T^a,T^b\right]^i_j=\delta_{aj}\delta_{bi}-\delta_{bj}\delta_{ai}$$
Which indeed is
$$[T^a,T^b]=\epsilon_{abc}T^c$$

Comment: Doesn't that evaluate to zero?

Comment: Sorry you're right, now should be ok and much clearer

Comment: I think it's still zero ^^

Comment: Check a little bit better... you just have to plug in correctly the formula I gave you with the deltas in the epsilon formula. If you still have a problem write me...